# SQL query for retrieving the time gap between the timestamp values

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, date-difference

i have two tables in oracle i need to write a SQL query for the following problem,

**Note:** client working hours are from morning `9 a.m.` to `6 p.m`

tab1 contains issue created and resolved time stamp,

In tab1 an issue was raised on `24th dec 2017` at `6:00 p.m` (at office closing time) and it was resolved on `26th dec 2017` at `10 a.m.` (just one hour after office opens)

i want to calculate the time between the issue created and resolved, in this case the time between these two is `"one hour"` because `25-dec-2017` is holiday

(holiday list is available in holiday table)

**condition 1:** if holiday dates are existed between the dates should be ignored

**condition 2:** if the weekend (saturday and sunday) are existed between these two dates (created and resolved) then it should be ignored.

Can anyone help me on this?

**tab1 and tab2:**

[image: tab1]

[image: tab2]

Comment: Are the issue_created_date and issue_resolved_date guaranteed to always be on work days, and within work hours? If so, then the problem is slightly easier than the most general case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a correlated subquery to find the number of holidays (weekends must be included in the holidays table) and use TIMESTAMP operations to achieve your result. This works for PostgreSQL, but should be easily adaptable for Oracle:

```
SELECT issue_created_date, issue_resolved_date, ((days_in_bet - downtime_days) * INTERVAL '24 HOUR') + hours AS total_hours
FROM
(
SELECT issue_created_date, eod_timestamp, issue_resolved_date, sod_timestamp, downtime_days, 
       CASE WHEN DATE_TRUNC('DAY', issue_created_date) <> DATE_TRUNC('DAY', issue_resolved_date) THEN DATE(sod_timestamp) - DATE(eod_timestamp) - 1 ELSE 0 END AS days_in_bet,
       CASE WHEN DATE_TRUNC('DAY', issue_created_date) = DATE_TRUNC('DAY', issue_resolved_date) THEN issue_resolved_date - issue_created_date
        ELSE (eod_timestamp - issue_created_date) + (issue_resolved_date - sod_timestamp) END AS hours
FROM
(
    SELECT issue_created_date, DATE_TRUNC('DAY',issue_created_date) + INTERVAL '18 HOUR' AS eod_timestamp,
                                                                                    issue_resolved_date, DATE_TRUNC('DAY',issue_resolved_date) + INTERVAL '9 HOUR' AS sod_timestamp,
                                                                                    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tab2 h WHERE h.holiday BETWEEN i.issue_created_date AND i.issue_resolved_date) AS downtime_days
    FROM tab1 i 
) a1
) a2
```

Note that an important assumption this query makes is that issues can be created AND resolved only on working days.

Output:

```
issue_created_date    |  issue_resolved_date  | response_time_hours
"2017-12-24 18:00:00"   "2017-12-26 10:00:00"   "01:00:00"
"2017-12-26 13:00:00"   "2017-12-26 18:00:00"   "05:00:00"
"2017-12-27 08:00:00"   "2017-12-27 10:00:00"   "02:00:00"
"2017-12-27 14:00:00"   "2017-12-28 09:30:00"   "04:30:00"
```

Comment: SELECT
 issue_created_date, 
DATE_TRUNC('DAY',issue_created_date) + INTERVAL '18 HOUR' AS eod_timestamp, 
issue_resolved_date, 
DATE_TRUNC('DAY',issue_resolved_date) + INTERVAL '9 HOUR' AS sod_timestamp, 
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tab2 h WHERE h.holiday BETWEEN i.issue_created_date AND i.issue_resolved_date) AS downtime_days 

FROM tab1 i  --What is sample output of this query could you please share